# T flip-flop using dataflow model

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, flip-flop

I'm trying to simulate the working of t-flipflop.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module t_flipflop(
input t,
input clk,
input clear,
output q,
output qbar
);

 wire sbar, rbar;
 
 assign sbar= ~(t & clk & qbar & clear);
 assign rbar= ~(t & clk & q);
 
 assign q= ~(sbar & qbar);
 assign  qbar= ~(rbar & q & clear);
endmodule
```

Now in output the value of q toggles when t=1, but the value of qbar is always 1.

Also when t=1, q is always 0 and qbar is 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Test fixture:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module test_t_flipflop;

// Inputs
reg t;
reg clk;
reg clear;

// Outputs
wire q;
wire qbar;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
t_flipflop uut (
    .t(t), 
    .clk(clk), 
    .clear(clear), 
    .q(q), 
    .qbar(qbar)
);

initial begin
    clear=1'b0;
    #34 clear=1'b1;
end

initial begin
    
    t=1'b0;
    clk=1'b0;
    forever #15 clk=~clk;
end

initial begin
    #10 t=1;
    #95 t=0;
    #40 t=1;
end
```

[image: output signals]

I want to implement this with the data flow model to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to model sequential logic with continuous assignments.  This can result in unpredictable simulation results.  For example, when I run your code using Incisive, it results in an infinite loop, which usually indicates a race condition.  I assume the race is due to the feedback path: `q` depends on `qbar` which in turn depends on `q`.

The proper way to model sequential logic is to use this register-transfer logic (RTL) coding style:

```
module t_flipflop (
    input t,
    input clk,
    input clear,
    output reg q,
    output qbar
);

assign qbar = ~q;

always @(posedge clk or negedge clear) begin
    if (!clear) begin
        q <= 0;
    end else if (t) begin
        q <= ~q;
    end
end
endmodule
```

This eliminates the feedback path and simplifies your code by eliminating the internal wires.  It can also be used for synthesis.